# adobe edgeaccessing variable within function

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval, adobe-edge

im fiddeling around with Adobe Edge animation and stumbled over a strange problem im hoping someone out there could help me with.

what i want to do is, accessing variables set within functions declared on the Stage... for my basic test, im starting an timer (setInterval) within compositionReady, along with a timer counter variable to move a symbol in runtime, this all works great, next thing is to have a basic button stopping this timer event, and here's my problem, since i've set the timer to a variable within the compositionReady function i can access the bloody variable, or at least i can figure out how.

any suggestion ? :)
are my thinking wrong about declaring variables?, if i set variables in the root of the Stage i can access them as globals, but this won't do well for my timer (setInterval function), coming from Actionscript 3, it's always a good idea to check if the "Stage" have init'ed properly before shooting new events :)

Here's my code copied from the Stage.. i have two symbols on the Stage textSymbol and another called RoundRect which is the button.

```
Symbol.bindElementAction(compId, symbolName, "document", "compositionReady", function(sym, e) {

    var timerVar = 0;
    var timer = setInterval(loop, 33);

    // OUR LOOP FUNCTION
   function loop(){
    timerVar++;
        sym.$('textSymbol').css('left', timerVar);
   }




});
//Edge binding end



Symbol.bindElementAction(compId, symbolName, "${_RoundRect}", "click", function(sym, e) {

   // SET THE SYMBOL BACK TO 0, UPDATED TO THE VARIABLE WITHIN THE TIMER EVENT
   sym.$('textSymbol').css('left', 0);


   alert(  sym.getComposition().getStage().getVariable('timerVar')  ); // return undefined


});
//Edge binding end
```

Comment: Okay i found it's best to declare variables outside the functions, which makes sense, but still is it possible to access var's within not to mention Functions which you declare within the compositionReady "symbol" or function which it properly is :)..

Answer (score 0):

removing var in my case actually helped. i created GSAP timeline variable and wanted to pause it on mouseover. since mouseover had no access to vars declared in creationComplete, removing "var" let me pause timeline from mouseover function.

Answer (score -1):

just remove the 'var' before your variable declaration so that it's global.